# I'm trying to make a program that converts hexadecimal to binary but my program is doing the opposite. How to fix this?

Tags: assembly, hex, x86-16

```
.model small
.stack
.data     
    msg1 db "Enter hexadecimal number:$"
    msg2 db "The binary value is:$"   
    msg3 db "The number of 1's is:$"
    msg4 db "The number of 0's is:$" 
    countone db ?
    countzero db ? 

.code       
main proc
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax  


    clear:
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,0dh
    int 21h
    mov dl,0ah
    int 21h

    mov ah,9
    lea dx,msg1
    int 21h

    xor bh,bh

    input:
    mov ah,1
    int 21h

    mov ch,al 

    cmp ch,0dh
    je print

    cmp ch,'0'
    jl exit

    cmp ch,'1'
    jg exit

    and ch,15
    shl bh,1
    or bh,ch  

    jmp input

print:
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,0dh
    int 21h
    mov dl,0ah
    int 21h

    mov ah,9
    lea dx,msg2
    int 21h

    mov ah,2

    cmp bh,9
    jle number

    cmp bh,15
    jle character

number:
    add bh,48
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,bh
    int 21h 

    mov ah,2
    mov dl,13
    int 21h
    mov dl,10
    int 21h

    mov ah,9
    lea dx,msg3
    int 21h

    mov ah,2
    mov dl,13
    int 21h
    mov dl,10
    int 21h

    mov ah,9
    lea dx,msg4
    int 21h 
    jmp clear


character:
    add bh,55
    mov ah,2
    mov dl,bh
    int 21h 

    mov ah,2
    mov dl,13
    int 21h
    mov dl,10
    int 21h

    mov ah,9
    lea dx,msg3
    int 21h

    mov ah,2
    mov dl,13
    int 21h
    mov dl,10
    int 21h

    mov ah,9
    lea dx,msg4
    int 21h 
    jmp clear





exit:
  mov ah,2
  mov dl,0dh
  int 21h
  mov dl,0ah 
  int 21h

  mov ah,4ch
  int 21h
 main endp
END main
```

Comment: Do you want to convert to a base-2 ASCII string, or an actual binary integer in a register?  Your code is long an uncommented, and not very readable.  But I see you want to print the number of 0s and 1s.  (Hint: just count one in the loop, get the other from subtracting.)   And BTW, you can count 0s / 1s without packing all the nibbles into a single register, because base 16 is a power of 2.
 maybe related: [How to return number in binary x86 assembly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/20199829).

Comment: Anyway, "doing the opposite" isn't specific enough for a [mcve].  Is it reading base 2 input and converting to hex??